# Is it possible to connect metamask in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: metamask, python, external-api

I would like to use my wallet to sign transactions using an api in a Jupyter notebook. To do this, I currently have to store the private key either in the notebook itself or in another file.

It would be really helpful if I could have a cell in my notebook that opens up a Metamask authorization and after that the whole notebook would be authorized to sign transactions using the api. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Any update on this one?

Comment: Yes, so far created a jupyterlab extension that connects to MetaMask, however, I don't yet know how to trigger transactions from python cells, it's only possible to call commands in the extension that then use javascript to trigger metamask signatures

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brownie (or eth-ape, which is taking the torch from brownie, it's just not all the way there with the documentation at the moment) to make transactions. Use an environment variable for your Private Key in your terminal and reference that environment variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Putting the private key in an environment variable is exactly what I would like to replace, since exposing your private key in any way is not best practice, especially when you want to interact with services on mainnet.